# IBM BPM process portal page not loading properly

Tags: business-process-management

After installing BPM 8.5.5, I could see process portal page loading the below way:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EHA9.jpg)

Tried both the http and https protocol. Need suggestions...

Answer (score 0):

Use FQDN (fully qualified domain name) instead of "localhost" in the URL and it should work. E.g. use the hostname of the BPM server that was used during the IBM BPM installation.

If not, then perform verification of Process Portal using the instructions from this link and post screenshot(s) of what you see -
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFTBX_8.5.6/com.ibm.wbpm.imuc.doc/topics/tcfg_process_portal_verify.html